# POST with JSON body consumed by RESTeasy - HTTP 100

Tags: php, rest, post, curl, resteasy

I have a very simple scenario which I cannot get to work. I am trying to POST a JSON string to a RESTful endoint using cURL to sent the request over HTTPS and RESTeasy on the server.

My cURL POST is configured thusly:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$content = json_encode($validJsonString);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://foobar.com/test?trackingId=12345');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $content));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$headers = array( 
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content)
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

$httpResponseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$json = json_decode($response);
curl_close ($ch);

return $json;
```

And the RESTeasy recipiant looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/json")
public String addObjectCommentAsJSON(   @FormParam("json") String validJsonString, 
                                        @QueryParam("trackingId") String trackingId) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SomeObject someObject = gson.fromJson(validJsonString, SomeObject.class);
    String responseString = methodThatReturnsAJsonString(trackingId, someObject);
    return responseString;
}
```

This issue I am having is that the request hangs for about 30 seconds and then returns a HTTP 100 response. I understand that HTTP 100 means continue with the remainder of the request but I don't understand how I am supposed to do that.

I tried to remove the Content-Length header but obviously I get a 411 (needs content length) so that's not an option either.

Is it an issue with the content type perhaps? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json

Comment: According to php.net if you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` it gets encoded for `multipart/form-data`. What happens if you pass the json string directly?

Comment: @cbuckley I saw that but there's no mention of RESTeasy in the other on and that is 50% of the potential issue here...

Comment: Refer to abraham's comment for the issue here. If content-type is application/json, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS should be given a string containing the output of json_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @cbuckley and @abraham's suggestions in their comments I have been able to work through the issues. This is what I needed to do:

1-> Change the contents of the POST body so instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $content));` I now have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($validJsonString));`

2-> I created a custom `@Provider` which parsed a JSON string to a Java POJO with the same structure:

> ```
> @Provider
> public class SomeObjectProvider implements StringConverter<SomeObject> {
>
>     private final Gson gson = new Gson();
>     public SomeObject fromString(String s) {
>         return gson.fromJson(s, SomeObject.class);
>     }
>
>     public String toString(SomeObject someObject) {
>         return gson.toJson(SomeObject);
>     } 
> }
> ```

3-> Finally the structure of the recipient method has to change slightly:

> ```
> @POST
> @Path("/test")
> @Produces("application/json")
> public String addObjectCommentAsJSON(SomeObject someObject,
>                                      @QueryParam("trackingId") String trackingId) {
>     String responseString = methodThatReturnsAJsonString(trackingId, someObject);
>     return responseString;
> }
> ```

And that all flowed through nicely.