# How do I POST Json value and some other values to another url using PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I have these values:

```
$time="2012-12-30 10:00:00";
$hash="DONE_ILK_ONAY_P_KEY__2012_2012-12-30 10:00:00";
```

And the JSON data to be sent are:

```
jsonRequest:
{
    "company_id":"somevalue",  
    "company _username":"somevalue", 
    "company _password":" somevalue", 
    "profile_id":"somevalue", 
    "profile_mail":"somevalue",
    "profile_info": {
        "name":"somevalue",
        "surname":"somevalue",
        "birthdate":"somevalue",
        "marital_status":"somevalue",
        "education_level":"somevalue",
        "school":"somevalue",
        "city":"somevalue"
    }
}
```

Now how do I post these values to another URL using PHP and get response in JSON from them?

Comment: How about using the [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) package?

Comment: Could you please post the code for that, as answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server-side only PHP solution:**

See this link: http://themekraft.com/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/

You can use a combination of PHP curl and json_encode to send JSON and recieve JSON as a response.

```
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );
$json_string = json_encode(array(1 => $jsonRequest, 2 => $time, 3 => $hash));     
$options = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password,
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );    
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json_result = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: We're doing something wrong here,
only $jsonRequest is the JSON value. the time and the hash aren't the JSON variables. Please correct the code. I used that, and its not working.

And what is the $username and $password?

Comment: Prakash - I'm not sure really. My example was more of a working model... not supposed to be an exact solution. Just getting you part of the way.

Answer (score 2):

JSON POST with jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I found this example on another stack overflow question:

```
$.ajax({     type: "POST",
    url: "[URL of JSON-aware endpoint]", // your POST target goes here     
    dataType: "json",    
     data: { [$jsonRequest, $time, $hash] }, 
     // message to send goes here    
      success: function (data)     
      {         

            // do something with result     
            } 
       }); 
</script>
```

You had a follow-up question about how to pass the jsonRequest AND the two other parameters $time and $hash.

Note that even though you had 3 parameters $time, $hash and $jsonRequest... because the ajax post argument is simply json... you can add all three parameters in the data argument for the $.ajax function like I did above: `data: [$jsonRequest, $time, $hash]`

I modified the example above to do this.

Comment: @Nicholas, Thanks for the answer. I have a question. I have to post three fields, like I said, $time, $hash and the json value. Is it possible to post all the three values with the method you said in PHP?

and what will be the method of adding JSON data? as the field is added as:
$r->addPostFields(); in php.net.

Please explain.

Comment: The data parameter input into the $.ajax function is a JSON argument. So you can simply send all the parameters you need to into a JSON array and then parse them on the server.

Comment: I custom tailored the answer above to meet your requirements. Mark as an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `dataType: "json"`, you don't need `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);`.

Comment: This will only work if the URL is on the same domain as the one you are on.  You can't use this to POST to "outside" URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the fix Rocket. I had pulled that from another link. Fixed.

Comment: This is a PHP + Jquery solution Prakash.

Comment: I want pure PHP solution, no client side code used. All the things are to be done in server side.