# Login using Curl Php (POST method)

Tags: php, jquery, curl

Hi every one,
             I have a login form which has mail id and password, on submit it should call an api which inturn generates a auth token. I have used POST method in Php curl but getting the following error.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 - Error report
.. some html styles..
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

and this is my ajax call..

```
function callapi()
{ 
data = new Object();
var email= document.getElementById("input01").value;
var pwd=document.getElementById("input02").value;
if(email != ""&& pwd != "")
{
data.Email = email;
data.Pwd = pwd;

}

jQuery.ajax({ 
  url: "http://localhost/stackato/nlogin.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType:"json",
  data:data,
  error: function (data) {
   alert('error--'+data);
  },
  success: function (data) { 

if(data=="invalid")
{

}
else
{

window.location.href="finalstackatolists1.html";
}



}
});

}
```

and this is my curl php page

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$scriptname = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; 
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$mail=$_POST["Email"];
$pwd=$_POST["Pwd"];
$action = $_POST["action"];


$nurl = str_replace($scriptname,"...the api...",$url);




//open connection

$ch = curl_init(); 
$data = array("username" => $mail, "password" => $pwd);                                                                    
$req_data = json_encode($data);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $nurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req_data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);


 //execute post

if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
}

if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == '500')
{
    header("Status: 500 Server Error");
}

curl_close($ch);


echo $result;


?>
```

(I tried it in REST-Client and the token has been generating)

Please help me to solve this.. thanks in advance..

Comment: I suspect `header('Content-type: application/json');` should be after `curl_close()`

Comment: @Dr.Dan: Tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: in your curl add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/json"))` also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json)

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: Tried it but getting the similar kind of error report but now its coming as "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Comment: @vignesh: comment the curl code and try to output the `$req_data`.Check the format is correct.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: ya tried it already, getting that correctly.

Comment: @vignesh: the error tell like server gets json data and syntax is not as it expected. You have to find out how a successful req looklike and form your json.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: the Json data (request) is in correct form only i guess {"username":"xxxx@yyyy.com","password":"xxxxx"} dont know else wrong with this.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: Got it now. actually in backend they have mentioned as userName and not as username, that is the problem. now its working. thnx 4 ur help

Comment: @vignesh: :) good work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify that the posted data is of type `JSON`

add this line to your curl code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```