# PHP Curl equivalent of command line curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a working command line curl command

```
curl -v -d '{"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {"username": "myusername", "password": "mypassword"}}}' -H 'Content-type: application/json' myurl
```

I am trying to write equivalent PHP curl command -

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, myurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array('json' => '{auth: {passwordCredentials : {username : myusername, password : mypassword }}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

I am having different response for both the calls.
I have doubt about setting the json data correctly.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Could you show the responses you are getting? How are they different? Which one is producing the result you are expecting?

Comment: The value in $data is not a valid JSON string. You need to use quotes just like in the command line curl example.

Comment: @samitha - My question is, am i doing something wrong while writing equivalent PHP curl command


 Floris - Command line works fine, 


command line response - <p>The document has moved <a href="https://dev-test01.servosity.com.lab/admin/">here</a>.</p> 


PHP response also is same but it is redirecting me to different url 

"https://dev-test01.servosity.com.lab/auth/login/?next=/admin/"


which shows that in command line it gets authenticated but in PHP it 
is not getting authenticated and redirecting me to login page in 

place of profile page. 

Thanks

Comment: Yes that makes sense; you are not forming the request properly. Did the solution in my answer not solve it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Along with your curl request, also send the HTTP header. For example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
```

And the post data should be:

```
$post_data = '{auth: {passwordCredentials : {username : myusername, password : mypassword }}}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: Good call about the header; not sure you can get away with `JSON` without the double quotes (see how `json_encode` did things in my answer)

Comment: using json_encode is the best practice. but for this case it will get away :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_encode` function to make sure that things are properly encoded.

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271654/1967396 .

In your case, it might look like this:

```
$authData = array(auth =>  array(passwordCredentials => array( username => floris, password => secret )));
```

and then you create the POST data with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json'=>json_encode($authData)));
```

If you do

```
print json_encode($authData);
```

you get

```
{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username":"floris","password":"secret"}}}
```

Presumably you could do this manually, without the `json_encode` function.

Comment: Thank you floris, i did not thought of this approach


By the way i wanted json string as - {"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username":"floris","password":"secret"},}}


"," after the first "}" .

Comment: You original example didn't have the comma. Why do you need it? Does this solve the problem for you?

Comment: i figured out , i don't need that. Thanks. It did not solved my problem completely as i am still getting same response but the part for which i am here (setting the json data correctly) is solved.

Comment: Oh, this is old. but the POSTFIELDS receives it as array?