# cURL return "There was an error processing the request"

Tags: php, json, curl

everyone!

I wanted to scrape [this site using SocialSite platform](http://www.dbmanetwork.com/SocialSite/schedule) by cURLing on the XHR link in it but it returns:

```
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

This is the cURL code:

```
curl "http://www.dbmanetwork.com/WebServices/PlannerFace.asmx/GetAppointments" \
  -H "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vdazkdnenkpzqjgdnjl24pz0; perfectmindmobilefeature=0" \
  -H "Origin: http://www.dbmanetwork.com" \
  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,jv;q=0.2" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" \
  -H "Referer: http://www.dbmanetwork.com/8661/Office/Planner/ScheduleView?layoutType=wide&objectId=63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-5289d7e766e9&viewId=2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702&text=Book&skinId=4494e024-c590-4daa-9bfd-e14a7709d23b" \
  -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" \
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
  --data-binary "{""schedulerInfo"":{""ViewStart"":""\\/Date(1430092800000)\\/"",""ViewEnd"":""\\/Date(1430697600000)\\/"",""LocationId"":""All Locations"",""IsReadOnly"":true,""UseAppointmentLocationTimezone"":true,""ApplicationType"":2,""OrgId"":""29f8130e-ea28-4cd7-8bb0-298f753d9d17"",""ObjectViewIdCombos"":""63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-5289d7e766e9.2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702""}}" \
  --compressed -k
```

The advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json) don't work since the cURL already fulfilled the required condition (`json_encode` and `Content-Type`).

Thx!

### UPDATE!

Using the `--verbose` flag, I got this result:

```js
* Adding handle: conn: 0x214d7e0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x214d7e0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.dbmanetwork.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 50.112.169.144...
* Connected to www.dbmanetwork.com (50.112.169.144) port 80 (#0)
> POST /WebServices/PlannerFace.asmx/GetAppointments HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.dbmanetwork.com
> Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vdazkdnenkpzqjgdnjl24pz0; perfectmindmobilefeature=0
> Origin: http://www.dbmanetwork.com
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,jv;q=0.2
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.
36
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> Referer: http://www.dbmanetwork.com/8661/Office/Planner/ScheduleView?layoutType=wide&objectId=63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-
5289d7e766e9&viewId=2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702&text=Book&skinId=4494e024-c590-4daa-9bfd-e14a7709d23b
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 346
>
* upload completely sent off: 346 out of 346 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< jsonerror: true
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
< Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 04:01:25 GMT
< Content-Length: 91
< Connection: Keep-Alive
<
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}* Connection #0 to host www.d
bmanetwork.com left intact
```

Comment: Can you add the `--verbose` option and post the output?

Comment: Sure @Jordan, I've added it to the bottom of the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to thank @rezashamdani
His answer wasn't the exact answer, but it gave me a strong hint until I could finally found it.

He said that the problem was with the `"\\/Date(1430697600000)\\/"` in the json string I sent. I might need to simulate the javascript date function. I found out in its [javascript file where the XHR executed](http://www.dbmanetwork.com/asset.axd?id=WgEAAB-LCAAAAAAABABtkNEKgjAUht_lXEtqLoPdBl0VFEY34cWYqybLydysEN-9k0Eqered__v-A6eBDOilgRIoJNzI0lZ-fnTCvDfaCPDg2sUFxv14L4tFXmGogQZt2npz_kG5myxmGhDTSp30sCX8dvTITnOmftyQWk53OStVNVqSMSu22jyYHarRRB1JCb-LzClxluL5dwg6qQfcImDFy_o5q1nV2QjUOA1IGAeErPHL8Y5RvMIHUGucaD9OmlWlWgEAAA%3D%3D) that the date string was reformatted using local function `toAspDateFormat` which changes `"/Date(1430697600000)/"` to `"\\/Date(1430697600000)\\/"`. It shows that the escape character is important. I change the `--data-binary` from my cURL to this: `"{""schedulerInfo"":{""ViewStart"":""\/Date(1430092800000)\/"",""ViewEnd"":""\/Date(1430697600000)\/"",""LocationId"":""All Locations"",""IsReadOnly"":true,""UseAppointmentLocationTimezone"":true,""ApplicationType"":2,""OrgId"":""29f8130e-ea28-4cd7-8bb0-298f753d9d17"",""ObjectViewIdCombos"":""63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-5289d7e766e9.2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702""}}"`

It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

seem that the target server http://www.dbmanetwork.com. 3594 IN A   50.112.169.144 is down.

salam dari jakarta :)

Comment: Btw, @rezashamdani, the XHR link works on the website itself, at this link http://www.dbmanetwork.com/SocialSite/schedule I think the website developer is genius or something, don't want us to access their data. The verbose result shows that I succeeded to connect to dbmanetwork.com anyway

Comment: sorry :) apparently they block the port used by curl :)
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-28 11:15 WIB
Nmap scan report for www.dbmanetwork.com (50.112.169.144)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
rDNS record for 50.112.169.144: ec2-50-112-169-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Not shown: 992 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
808/tcp  closed ccproxy-http
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
8081/tcp closed blackice-icecap
8082/tcp closed blackice-alerts
8086/tcp closed d-s-n
9090/tcp closed zeus-admin

Comment: Hmmm, the first time I know cURL can be blocked. Do you ever try to force scrape to this kind of URL? How to make them don't know we are pulling data from cURL?
And how did you check that? I wanted to be able to do it myself. Thx! :D

Comment: one moment, i'll dig into this issue

Comment: Yup, that's the result I got when curling using PHP. What are you trying to say?

Comment: just doing a quick dig. the curl doesnt run javascript function within the target, while the data list was loaded by http://www.dbmanetwork.com/asset.axd?id=WgEAAB-LCAAAAAAABABtkNEKgjAUht_lXEtqLoPdBl0VFEY34cWYqybLydysEN-9k0Eqered__v-A6eBDOilgRIoJNzI0lZ-fnTCvDfaCPDg2sUFxv14L4tFXmGogQZt2npz_kG5myxmGhDTSp30sCX8dvTITnOmftyQWk53OStVNVqSMSu22jyYHarRRB1JCb-LzClxluL5dwg6qQfcImDFy_o5q1nV2QjUOA1IGAeErPHL8Y5RvMIHUGucaD9OmlWlWgEAAA%3d%3d , so curl is not possible in this issue CMIIW, try something that simulate javascript actions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue where I was getting the following response from the source for the curl request that I was using:

```
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

when I checked the verbose info adding the flag: --verbose

I got to know that I too was sending an incorrect json data payload with my curl request which was working in the terminal when I tried it, but was failing when I was making the curl request through the following python library:

```
from curllibrary.curl import curl
```

sending the curl request as:

```
# using the same curl request given in the question to demonstrate an example

curl_request = """curl "http://www.dbmanetwork.com/WebServices/PlannerFace.asmx/GetAppointments" \
  -H "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vdazkdnenkpzqjgdnjl24pz0; perfectmindmobilefeature=0" \
  -H "Origin: http://www.dbmanetwork.com" \
  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,jv;q=0.2" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" \
  -H "Referer: http://www.dbmanetwork.com/8661/Office/Planner/ScheduleView?layoutType=wide&objectId=63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-5289d7e766e9&viewId=2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702&text=Book&skinId=4494e024-c590-4daa-9bfd-e14a7709d23b" \
  -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" \
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
  --data-binary $"{""schedulerInfo"":{""ViewStart"":""\\/Date(1430092800000)\\/"",""ViewEnd"":""\\/Date(1430697600000)\\/"",""LocationId"":""All Locations"",""IsReadOnly"":true,""UseAppointmentLocationTimezone"":true,""ApplicationType"":2,""OrgId"":""29f8130e-ea28-4cd7-8bb0-298f753d9d17"",""ObjectViewIdCombos"":""63be552d-cb71-40e7-aa6f-5289d7e766e9.2cb73398-53ff-4a9e-adda-3444fb771702""}}" \
  --compressed -k"""

curl_response = curl(curl_request)
```

since I was using the ***'$'*** in front of the raw data that I was sending which was causing the request to fail, so as soon as I removed the dollar sign, it worked and I got the expected response that I was getting in the terminal.

Hope this ends up resolving an issue for someone who is facing this type of problem.