# curl post Json with addslashes

Tags: php, json, curl, post

I need:

```
$content = "{\"data1\":90,\"data2\":\"SUKAORU\",\"data3\":7483478334}";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content);
```

I did:

```
   $_REQUEST = array("data1"=>90,"data2"=>"SUKAORU,"data3"=>7483478334);

    $content1 = '"' . addslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST)) . '"';
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content1);

//or
    $content1 = addslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST));
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content1);

//or
    $content1 = json_encode($_REQUEST);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content1);
```

**$content** and **$content1** looks identically:

[image]

But second version returns error from server "unable to decode request".

How can I ecranate array into JSON like in I need example?

Comment: Why not `curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($content));`

Comment: `$_REQUEST = array` — Don't overwrite `$_REQUEST`. If you want a variable to store your own data in, create a new one.

Comment: Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271621/php-curl-post-json  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));`

Comment: Is it a typing mistake `"data2"=>"SUKAORU,"`? It should be "data2"=>"SUKAORU",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `addslashes`. Just don't use it.

The slashes here:

> ```
> $content = "{\"data1\":90,\"data2\":\"SUKAORU\",\"data3\":7483478334}";
> ```

… are only part of the **PHP source code**. They are not part of the data.

If you're generating the JSON using `json_encode` then you don't need to manually write `\"` to get quotes into the `"` delimited string literal. You don't have a string literal and `json_encode` is generating the quotes.

---

This should be fine.

```
$data = array("data1"=>90,"data2"=>"SUKAORU","data3"=>7483478334);
$json = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json);
```

Note addition of missing `"` after `"SUKAORU`.

Comment: you are right, I think it was server temporarily problem, my previous code now works fine, still don't know why `json_encode($_REQUEST,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`